# How can I export all my Terminal.app settings from one Mac to another?

Tags: macos, terminal.app

I want to set a group of terminal windows, each one with personalized colours, etc.

How can I move the whole Terminal.app setting from one computer to another? Where are they stored?

Can't see them in $HOME/Library/Application Support/ nor in /Library/Application Support/

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist` contains Terminal settings.

You can view the file (if you want to) with `Property List Editor`, part of Apple's developer tools. Copy it to to your other machine to take your settings with you.

You can also export one `Settings` entry in Terminal by selecting `Shell`, `Export Settings...`, or by pressing the cog button below the list in `Terminal Preferences`, `Settings` and choosing `Export...`.

Comment: Perfect! Just copied the aforementioned com.apple.Terminal.plist from my iMac (pretty Terminal setup) to my Macbook Pro boring terminal setup and now both are identical. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Copying the com.apple.Terminal.plist works very well. Be sure, however, to NOT have Terminal running when you copy the file as it will overwrite it when it exits.

Comment: Or if you have Terminal running you can do `defaults read com.apple.Terminal` after copying the file, and then restart Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

on Macos Mojave 10.14.6 , copy of the preference file did not work even with terminal closed.

So I used this method:

- open a finder window and terminal preferences.
- select all terminal settings, and then drag and drop to finder.
- This creates *.terminal files
- copy those files, and do opposite, drag from finder to terminal settings.